# Why URLRequest stops a Tween animation on flash (AS3) and how to solve it?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Hi guys im using flash with AS3 and i use the instruction `var myTween:Tween = new Tween(waves, "y", Strong.easeOut, waves.y, puntop, 3, true);` for making simple animations, the think is that when i call a *URLRequest* the animation just stop and freeze. How can i solve this? Thanks!

Comment: What are you passing the `URLRequest` to, a `URLStream`?  Post the code you have attached to the `COMPLETE` event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution might be to use a different Tweening engine than the flash utils.  Try TweenMax.

http://www.greensock.com/tweenmax/